# How to change the Material Design TextInputLayout Hint Text Color?

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I'm trying to set the `hintTextColor` **AND** the `boxStrokeColor` of Material Design's `textInputLayout` into 3 different state of colors, for example:

- **red** for when it's `disabled` (I don't know how to set the `boxStrokeColor` in `disabled` state, so please don't mind the screenshot)

[image]

- **blue** for when it's `enabled` but `unfocused`

[image]

- **green** for when it's `enabled` AND `focused`

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

For the `hintTextColor`, I've tried the suggestion made by [Gabriele Mariotti](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti) in [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1492#issuecomment-661249232), but the problem is one of the colors is applied to two different states ([`disabled`] and [`enabled` but `unfocused`]), and I want to differentiate these two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom style:

```
<style name="CustomOutlineBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/text_color_hint</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

with the `@color/text_color_hint` selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/red" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/blue"/>
</selector>
```

and the `@color/text_input_layout_stroke_color` selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/green" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/green" android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/red" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:alpha="..." android:color="@color/blue"/>  <!-- unfocused -->
</selector>
```

Focused:

[image]

Unfocused:

[image]

Disabled:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It was actually just a dumb mistake on my part.
Now I'm going to always remember to disable the `TextInputLayout`, not the `TextInputEditText`. :)